# New to Microservices - refactoring a monolith "Marketplace" database

Tags: oop, microservices

I am new to microservices and have been struggling to wrap my brain around it. On the surface they sound like a good idea, but from a practical standpoint, I can't break away from my centralized database background. For an example, I have this real-world Marketplace example that I cannot figure out if microservices would help or hurt. This site was working well until the PO asked for "Private Products." Now it is fragile and slow so I need to do a major refactor. A good time to implement microservices. I feel like many systems have this type of coupling, so that deconstructing this example would be very instructive.

**Current State**

This is a b2b marketplace where users belong to companies that are buying products from each other. Currently, there exists a monolithic database: User, Company, Catalog, Product, and Order. (This is a simplification, the actual scenario is much more complicated, users have roles, orders have header/detail, products have inventories, etc.)

- Users belong to Companies
- Companies have a Catalog of their Products
- Companies have Orders for Products from other Companies

So far so good. I could see breaking the app into microservices on the major entity boundaries.

**New Requirement**

Unfortunately for my architectural aspirations, the product owner wants more features. In this case: Private Products.

- Products are Public or Private
- Companies send time-bound Invitations to Products or Catalogs to Users of other Companies

This seemingly simple request all the suddenly complicated everything.

**Use Case - User displays a list of products**

For example, listing or searching products was once just a simple case of asking the Products to list/search themselves. It is one of the top run queries on the system. Unfortunately, now what was a simple use case just got messy.

- A User should be able to see all public Products (easy)
- A User should be able to see all their own Company's private Products (not horrible)
- A User can see any Product that their Company has Ordered in the past regardless of privacy (Uh oh, now the product needs to know about the User Company's Order history)
- A User can see any private Product for which they have an active Invitation (Uh oh, now the product needs to know about the User's Product or Catalog Invitations which are time dependent)

**Initial Monolithic Approach**

This can be solved at the database level, but the SQL joins basically ALL of the tables together (and not just master data tables, all the transactions as well.) While it is a lot slower than before, since a DBMS is designed for big joins it seems like the appropriate tool. So I can start working on optimizing the query. However, as I said, for this and other reasons the system is feeling fragile.

**Initial Design Thoughts... and ultimately my questions**

So considering a Microservices architecture as a potential new direction, I began to think about how to start. Data redundancy seems necessary. Since, if I translate my major entities into services, asking to get a list of products without data redundancy would just have all of the services calling each other and a big slow mess.

Starting with a the idea of carving out "Product and Catalog" as its own microservice. Since Catalogs are just collections of Products, they seem to belong together - I'll just call the whole thing the "Product Service". This service would have an API for managing both products and catalogs and, most importantly, to search and list them.

As a separate service, to perform a Product search would require a lot of redundant data as it would have to subscribe to any event that affected product privacy, such as:

- Listen for Orders and keep at least a summary of the relationship between purchased Products and Purchasing Companies
- Listen to Invitations and maintain a list of **active** User/Product/Time relationships
- Listen to User and Company events to maintain a User to Company relationship

I begin to worry about keeping it all synchronized.

In the end, a Product Service would have a large part of the current schema replicated. So I begin to think, maybe Microservices won't work for this situation. Or am I being melodramatic and the schema will be simpler enough to be more managable and faster so it is worth it?

Overall, am I thinking about this whole approach properly? Is this how microservice based designs are intended to be thought through? If not, can somebody give me a push in a different direction?

Comment: Don’t suddenly refactor everything to microservices alongside your other refactoring unless you have time to tear them back down and build a normal service.

Comment: This is an educational example for myself to make sure I understand microservices at all. I definitely won't be rushing to refactor anything. However, we are about to launch into a major new version, so it is now or never. Or at least, I can start moving in that direction by doing my smaller refactoring with a mind toward eventually carving a piece out as a separate service. I'm just not confident I have a clear picture of what such a future state should look like.

Comment: I'd suggest you watch Udi Dahan's video [about decomposing business entities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTArpO7rSQE) this may put you on the right path? Be happy to help more if I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting your system into services over and over until it makes sense. Use your gut feeling. Read more books, articles, forums where other people describing how they did it.

You've mentioned that there is no point of splitting ProductService into Product and ProductSearch - fair enough, try to implement it like that. If you will end up with a pretty complicated schema for some reason or with performance bottlenecks - it's a good sign to continue splitting further. If not - it is fine like that for your specific domain.

Not all product services made equal. In some situations, you have to be able to create millions or even billions of products per day. In this situation, it is most likely that you should consider separating product catalogue and product search. The reason is performance: to make search perform faster (indexing) you have to slow down inserts. These are two mutually exclusive goals that are hard to reach without separating data into different microservices (which will lead to data duplication as well).

Comment: Good points. One thing on the table was to implement a search engine like SOLR for search. Separating out the services would make this possible, because the Product Search service could eventually just be replaced by a SOLR wrapper.